# Widget receiver stops working after application is updated

Tags: android, widget

I have a strange problem with a widget I developed. The widget works normally on the home screen, updating as it should. I have recently made some changes to the code, adding some more intents to the widget receiver.

The original intent filter for the widget was the following:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
</intent-filter>
```

After the changes, I added the following intents:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.basi.widget.MY_UPDATE_WIDGET" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_CHANGED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED" />
</intent-filter>
```

and changed the widget from being updated by a service to being updated by an recurring alarm that sends the MY_UPDATE_WIDGET intent.
The problem is that when I update the application, the widget stops updating and a 'Problem loading widget' appears. When I remove the widget from the home screen and add it back, it works as it should, even if I install further updates. It looks like something goes wrong with the particular update, i.e., the changing of the intents. I have checked the logcat and there are no errors but I have noticed that the onReceive intent is not firing up after the initial update so that is probably the problem.

What I suspect is that a widget already on a home screen knows which intents to receive - if it is not re-initialized (by removing it and adding it back), it will not listen to the new intents so that is why the problem happens. Is there a way to tell the widget to start receiving the new intents? Is it a different problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of trial and error I found out what was the problem. One of the changes I made in the update was to move the widget class into a different package in the updated version. This seems to 'break' the functionality of existing widgets after the package is replaced with the new version. Moving the widget class file back to the original package fixed the problem. There is nothing wrong with the additional intents.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Have proguard in use, which would explain why I´m facing the same issue. Thank you